# How to monitor prices of apps in App Store

Tags: api, store

Now, I can get prices of apps using the `search` and `lookup` APIs. But I don't know how to monitor the prices. Should I check all the apps using API every day or even every some hours? It seems to be a huge task.

And here's another question. How can I get info of "all" the apps since the APIs needs keyword or id parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to index them initially, then index the most popular keywords that you're looking for, so you can search for those and update the prices if necessary. In terms of actually scanning the entire app store every few hours, that seems a bit much. Can you expand on what you'll be doing with this information?

Comment: I want to monitor time limited free apps as many alike sites do. So I need the price history.

Comment: Hey Allen. It's quite old, but did you find out?